# Is there a way to restrict the buttons on a standard page to be top only

Tags: administration, page-layout

Was wondering if there is a way to show the button on a standard page to be available only on the top of the page instead of displaying both and top and bottom of the page.

Thanks

Comment: What about JS trick? I have done such kind of thing using JS script that just removes the bottom buttons by css class name. jQuery('div.pbBottomButtons').remove();

Comment: Where would i have the js included?

Comment: The JS code can be placed in S-Control or just in any custom button. If you use the S-Control then you have to put it in the page layout and hide it(width: 1, height: 1) so the code should be like this var el = windo.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('pbBottomButtons')[0]; el.parentNode.removeChild(el);

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Comment: an inline VF page with JQUERY is the only option

Answer (score -1):

Like Save/Edit on a VF page? `apex:pageBlockButtons` has a parameter `location` where you can specify top, bottom, or both - it defaults to both.

https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockButtons.htm

Comment: Yeah.. it would work on VF page. i was looking at how to do it on standard page using pagelayout or any other method

Comment: Question was asked for standard layout